# Logging sql commands but not committing them

Tags: postgresql, logging, transactions

I'm looking for some advice for a system that has a "dry run" mode that will be used to help with the QA of data transformations. The idea is to be able to log and report what would happen to the database and then apply that log if not in dry run mode.

We've considered creating a sort of common format csv file but that has limited us. My other thought was to log the sql inserts/updates/deletes so we can view them in dry run and apply them in production mode, but that certainly adds work and the concern regarding sql injection (though I can use parameterized queries).

What would be ideal is to use something within postgres, such as using rollback transactions but then get the sql output from within those transactions.

Has anyone had to solve for something like this? Is this kind of a pipedream that may be more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: Providing some more context about the application(s) interacting with the database might help.  Are there multiple different clients / applications, or just one, for example?

Comment: Sure. This is an ETL type application written in .NET that loads data from files into a PostgreSQL database. I only want this type of logging for this particular application and use case.

Comment: In that case, your original idea of an application mode which writes the queries to stdout or to a file, rather than executing them, seems like a perfectly reasonable and is a common solution for dry run.  But why do you want to be able to apply the database update from the log file, rather than by re-running the same application with the same inputs?

Comment: Your response is something I've been mulling over. The original idea was to have one component produce all of the output and the final step in the pipeline is a "dumb loader" that would load from the file or not depending on it being in dry run mode. I think that idea is becoming complex and I'm leaning more on what you said which is to pass the "dry run" parameter to the loader and let it decide to either log or commit. Thank you for your time and idea.